# Memory Leaks in Typescript when using Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having this piece of code in Typescript

```
const f = async function() {
    return 1+1;
};

let memory = process.memoryUsage();
let i = 0;
while (i < 100000) {
    let result = await f().then(function(res) {}).catch(function() {});
    i++;
}
let memory2 = process.memoryUsage();
console.log(memory2.heapUsed - memory.heapUsed);
```

The more iterations I make, the bigger is the heapUsed between both points.

By reducing the method properly, and not using promises but a simple method, the heap used turns stable and doesn't change even if I iterate 1 milion times.

```
const f = function() {
    return 1+1;
};

let memory = process.memoryUsage();
let i = 0;
while (i < 200000) {
    let r = f();
    i++;
}
let memory2 = process.memoryUsage();
console.log(memory2.heapUsed - memory.heapUsed);
```

Can anyone explain a little bit where is exactly the memory leak here? Where is the point where something stays in memory ad eternum?

Comment: Not sure it's a leak. Your function hasn't exited when you're printing out stats, so nothing is getting GC'd. It will get collected at some point.

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone explain a little bit where is exactly the memory leak here

Memory *usage* is not memory *leakage*. If memory can be garbage collected its not *leaking*. Your example is simply not big enough to warrant a GC run.

The following code runs the gc *forcefully* (not recommended!):

```
const f = async function () {
    return 1 + 1;
};

async function main() {
    let memory = process.memoryUsage();
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 100000) {
        let result = await f().then(function(res) {}).catch(function() {});
        i++;
    }
    console.log('before', process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - memory.heapUsed);
    global.gc();
    console.log('after', process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - memory.heapUsed);
}

main();
```

And if you run this you will notice that `after` the gc run memory actually decreases from the start of the application. Example runs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you put a 1 or 2 second setTimeout and the end of it all and then check your memory usage again, you’ll find that your memory is back down again. Because you are using an asynchronous function in your synchronous loop, those iterations are all being stored in memory while they wait for the stack to clear out (which wouldn’t happen until *after* your code is done executing, including the memory checks).

Comment: To clarify: you don’t necessarily have a leak here. A leak would be like maintaining access to variables within those asynchronous functions, which would prevent the GC from clearing out memory related to those scopes.

Comment: So, what happens if this process, instead of using this easy call, is managing several actions, and I need to maintain this process over the time (let's say an exportation)?

If I want to reach the end of the process, and this means managing thousands of entities, but the GC doesn't really do its work until the process finishes, how can I really force the GC to do the work?

Comment: Added a setTimeout of 3 seconds after all, and the memory usage never goes down

Comment: What are the memory statistics exactly? I just ran some tests with your synchronous code and found that the variable `i` being used to loop is what is causing the memory to appear to balloon.

Comment: (Edit: See basarat's answer for GC forcing.) GC will search through all of the memory that has been allocated and see what is inaccessible (out of scope in your JS), and then remove that stuff. If you have an async process running in your loop, as long as that process is still alive, the GC can't eliminate any variables stored within that iteration's scope, because they need to be available if the async task refers to them before it completes. You can try to use `await` to ensure your task exits before the loop moves on to the next iteration.